# Doing a lot of date comparing in a smarter way

Tags: javascript

I am making a booking system where I have to increase or decrease prices based on high season / low season etc.

Here is the final function after some good help from Alessandro :)
It now works without the need to a year in the season array.

```
    var seasonArray = [ 
        {
            "season": "HIGH Season",
            "from": 101,
            "to": 315,
            "pct": 30
        },
        {
            "season" : "MIDDLE Season",
            "from": 316,
            "to": 615,
            "pct" : 10
        },
        {
            "season" : "LOW Season",
            "from": 616,
            "to": 915,
            "pct" : -10
        }
    ]

    var checkin  = Date.parse('2017-01-01 00:00:00')
    var checkout = Date.parse('2017-09-05 00:00:00')

    calcPrice(checkin, checkout);

function calcPrice(checkin, checkout){
    var nights    = daysBetween(new Date(checkin), new Date(checkout))
    var totPrice  = calcPeriod(nights,checkin);
    var avgPrice  = Math.round(totPrice/nights);
    totPrice      = avgPrice * nights //compensate for math.round difference
    var finalPrice = 0;
    for (var d = new Date(checkin); d <= checkout; d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1)) {
        dn = Number((d.getMonth()+1) + ('0' + d.getDate()).slice(-2)) 
        var season = seasonArray.find(item => {
           return item.from <= dn && item.to >= dn
        });
        var pct = season ? season.pct : 0;
        finalPrice += avgPrice * (1 + pct / 100);
    }
    finalPrice = Math.round(finalPrice)
    console.log('totPrice: ' + totPrice)
    console.log('finalPrice: ' + finalPrice)
}
```

Comment: Show us your code instead of pseudo-code please

Comment: let me do a bit of cleanup first, so its presentable :-D

Comment: Don't clean up your code. Show us what you have and we will help you to optimize it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an approach like following:

- Create a seasonArray with date range (you could easily change current year in my example with a variable)
- Loop on each day from checkin to checkout
- And finally use the `find` function to get the right "season" for adjusting the final price

See my example to start (it could be improved):

```js
var seasonArray = [{
  "season": "HIGH Season",
  "from": Date.parse('2017-01-01 00:00:00'),
  "to": Date.parse('2017-03-15 23:59:59'),
  "pct": 30
}, {
  "season": "MIDDLE Season",
  "from": Date.parse('2017-03-16 00:00:00'),
  "to": Date.parse('2017-06-15 23:59:59'),
  "pct": 10
}, {
  "season": "LOW Season",
  "from": Date.parse('2017-06-16 00:00:00'),
  "to": Date.parse('2017-09-15 23:59:59'),
  "pct": -10
}]

var checkin = Date.parse('2017-01-06 00:00:00');
var checkout = Date.parse('2017-05-18 00:00:00');

var days = (checkout / 1000 - checkin / 1000) / 86400; //seconds per day
var totPrice = 13200;
var avgPrice = totPrice / days;
var finalPrice = 0;

for (var d = new Date(checkin); d <= checkout; d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1)) {
    var season = seasonArray.find(item => {
       return item.from <= d && item.to >= d
    });
    var pct = season ? season.pct : 0;
    finalPrice += avgPrice * (1 + pct / 100);
}
console.log("Final price is: " + finalPrice);
```

I hope it helps you, bye

edited: I added a little check on possible npe

> var pct = season ? season.pct : 0;

Comment: Thank you so much Alessandro - very elegant solution, and it WORKS!! except for one small thing.  The seasons are supposed to work for every year, so we cant put "2017" in the seasons array. 

is there a way to fix the `item.from <= d && item.to >= d` so it automatically put the year from "d" to the from/to items?

Comment: Hmm no that wont work - how about treating the from/to items as a number like 116 = 16th Jan and 1224 = 24th Dec.   and then turn "d" into that same number?

Comment: yep, that did the trick - I will post above in the question so you can see.  And its pretty damn fast!  Thanks so much for helping out.

Comment: I'm glad it helped you... bye